# Grid is not working properly

Tags: html, css, grid

I wanted to make a site with the grid system. ( I have made one already, so I know/knew how it works )

This is my custum grid: http://grids.heroku.com/grid.css?column_width=100&column_amount=8&gutter_width=15

And now comes the problem: When I try to put prefix_1 as a class nothing happen it just stays in the same place. And I have one prefix_1 grid_3 and one grid_4. so it is 1+3+4=8. My grid is 8 columns wide so it has to fit together easily, but it doesn't.
http://jsfiddle.net/gekkeabt/5LA82/

```
<div class="container_8">
<span id="download" class="prefix_1 grid_3"><a href="#"><b>Download</b> Leasy CMS</a></span>
<span id="download" class="grid_4"><a href="#"><b>Download</b> Macha Webserver</a></span>
<span id="about" class="prefix_2 grid_4 suffix_2"><a href="#"><b>About</b> Me</a></span>
</div>
```

I checked my code 100 times. But I can't find where it went wrong.

Maybe someone can help me out?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I solved the prefix and suffix problem by defining the class in another div outside of the span.
So it looks like:

```
<div class="prefix_1 grid_3"><span id="download">The content....</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the

```
padding:10px 50px 10px 50px;
```

line from your `#download,#about` CSS declaration (or at least the horizontal padding of 2 x 50px).

It's that extra padding that makes the elements wider than one row.

Here's how it looks without that line: http://jsfiddle.net/WHG4u/

Comment: Thank you! That did the job for not showing it next to each other.

Answer (score -1):

Please add this css to your /css/custom.css to make the page stop jumping each time the slide changes

```
.avia-content-slider-active .slide-entry-wrap { height: 275px; }
```